# Предлагается проверка собственной правки

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

схожая аномалия: [Предлагается переоткрытие мною же исправленного вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1429/178576)

---

Уже дважды сталкивался с такой ситуацией.

Если после редактирования чужого сообщения оно попадает в [очередь сообщений «плохого качества»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), то мне же, автору правки, при обработке этой очереди, предлагается её (правку) «проверить».

По-моему, это неправильно: внёсший правку не должен её «проверять», даже на предмет «плохого качества».

Comment: Я тоже уже несколько раз сталкивался с таким. Вам предлагают проверять не вашу правку. а пост, который был (скорее всего, ещё до вашей правки) расценен как пост "плохого качества". По сути, можно спокойно нажимать "Ничего делать не нужно", ведь вы уже сделали с постом всё, что могли. А вот правильно ли то, что после правки пост всё равно остаётся (без переоценки) в списке плохих - непонятно.

Comment: @Regent, только что столкнулся с аналогичной ситуацией: [*вопрос*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434619/178576) попал в очередь явно после моего изменения: через минуту после правки он был в очереди сообщений плохого качества. p.s. я понимаю, что в очередь попадают не правки, а сообщения, но само попадание в очередь вызвано именно внесением правки.

Comment: Интересное дело. Но и до правки ведь вопрос скорее всего рисковал оказаться в этой очереди. Видимо, и после правки вопрос выглядит сомнительным для системы.

Comment: проблема не в самом факте попадания в очередь, а в том, **кому** предложено проверить.

Comment: Это тоже понятно. Если вопрос после правки целенаправленно попадает в очередь, то тогда действительно имеет смысл не показывать его автору правки.

Comment: @Regent: правка не гарантирует, что вопрос или ответ стал лучше, или что он вообще «спасаемый». Например, исправлены грамматические ошибки, но ответ по-прежнему содержит только ссылку, но не решение.

Comment: Если бы вам предлагалось проверять собственную правку, то это была бы ошибка. В данном случае правка и «качество» сообщения не жёстко связаны. Проверяете вы не правку, а сообщение в целом. Наверняка, если вы одновременно с правкой проголосуете за закрытие, то в очереди оно вам уже не попадётся.