# Предлагается переоткрытие мною же исправленного вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Чем-то похоже на эту аномалию: [Предлагается проверка собственной правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/589/178576)

---

Неоднократно сталкивался с такой ситуацией:

После внесения исправления в уже закрытый вопрос он попадает в [очередь на переоткрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) (что нормально), и предъявляется **мне же** (внёсшему правку) для принятия решения — открывать вопрос или не открывать.

По-моему, это неправильно: внёсший правку в вопрос не должен принимать решение, открывать или нет исправленный вопрос.

**дополнение**

внося правку в закрытый вопрос и/или нажимая под ним ссылку `переоткрыть`, пользователь **уже** отдаёт свой голос за переоткрытие.

фактически получается, что, встретив тот же самый вопрос в очереди проверок на переоткрытие, пользователь может проголосовать за переоткрытие **второй** раз.

Answer (score 2):

Почему не должен? Он же все равно может зайти и оставить голос за открытие напрямую.

Можно рассматривать попадание в очередь просто как напоминание внесшему правку об этой возможности.

Вопросы, на которых стоит "требует правки", правят прежде всего ради их переоткрытия. Если человек не проголосовал за открытие сразу же - значит, скорее всего, он или забыл это сделать, или просто не знал о такой возможности.

Comment: *Почему не должен?* — возможно, я понимаю неверно идею **коллективных** проверок (review) как таковых, но, по-моему, проверять **что-либо** должны **другие** пользователи, а **не** инициатор проверки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Очередь на переоткрытие - это не проверка правки. Это предложение проголосовать за переоткрытие вопроса. Инициировать переоткрытие можно неявно - правкой и/или явно - голосом за переоткрытие. От того, что проверка была инициирована правкой, ваше право голоса никуда не исчезает.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: автору вопроса он на проверку наверняка не попадёт, а все остальные пользователи могут проверять. Не правка же проверяется, а вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну и в целом - было бы странно запрещать тем, кто внес любую правку в вопрос, голосовать за открытие. Поправил теги - все, не можешь переоткрыть?

Comment: @PashaPash, *было бы странно запрещать* — по-моему, никакого запрета нет. // у достигшего достаточной репутации есть право: 1. нажать кнопку `переоткрыть`; 2. внести правку. любым из этих двух способов он передаёт сообществу сигнал — этот вопрос сто́ит переоткрытия. всё, теперь уже **другие** пользователи должны принять решение, как реагировать на этот сигнал: открыть, оставить закрытым или **внести дополнительные правки**. если же инициатор попадает в число проверяющих, то тем самым он как бы «отбирает» возможность у ещё одной «пары глаз» взглянуть на вопрос и принять **своё** решение.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin он точно так же может "забрать" это право просто проголосовав за открытие сразу же после правки. прямой голос за открытие, без правки -  "забирает право", уменьшая количество необходимых голосов. в очереди попадают все вопросы, по отношению к которым вы *можете* принять соответствующее действие.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я склоняюсь к тому, что эта ситуация скорее "ты правил вопрос, и похоже забыл проголосовать за открытие" чем, "ок, ты исправил вопрос, теперь другие должны решить, открыть его, или нет. а ты можешь, но почему-то не должен"

Comment: @NickVolynkin, PashaPash, я внёс дополнение в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

После любой правки вопрос может стать лучше, вне зависимости от автора правки. Поэтому инициируется проверка: а не стал ли вопрос лучше, не стоит ли его переоткрыть?

Возможно, если вы отредактируете и сразу же проголосуете за переоткрытие, то в очереди правок вопрос не встретите (надо проверить). А если не проголосовали, то система напомнит — а вдруг вы забыли?

Comment: Точно не встретит. А тот же вопрос уже был открыт в просмотре очереди (например, в другом табе) - то после обновления вам напишет "не подлежит проверке".

Comment: *система напомнит — а вдруг вы забыли* — нет, «система» помещает вопрос в очередь проверок после сигнала о том, что вопрос сто́ит переоткрытия. см. [другой мой комментарий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429/1431#comment4093_1430).